# Append a new key to a list of dictionaries received from some API

Tags: python, json, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to add one key to my list of dictionaries that is `displayName` from one API response.
Source API contains one ID that is in other dict, the other dict also has `displayName` that I want from there.

I am getting **same value printed every time** when I dump this data into a file.

```
up = {}
li = []
for instance in instances:
    for key, value in instance.items():
        up.setdefault(key, value)
        if key == 'instance_id':
            for node in temp:
                if value == (node.get('ec2VirtualMachineSummary', {}).get('instanceID', {})):
                    up.setdefault('displayName', node.get('displayName'))
    li.append(up)
```

This is source

```json
{
    "instance_id": "ABC XYZ",
    "instance_type": "ABC XYZ",
    "Resource is Exposed to Public": "ABC XYZ",
}
```

This is expected.

```json
{
    "instance_id": "ABC XYZ",
    "instance_type": "ABC XYZ",
    "Resource is Exposed to Public": "ABC XYZ",
     ** "displayName": "This value is that I am adding" **
}
```

Comment: > I am getting same value printed every time ...
-- This is most likely caused by reusing the `up` dictionary over and over again. `up.setdefault()` only has an effect if the key is not existing already. So, perhaps only in the first iteration of your loop.  -- But your problem seems to be that "displayName" _never_ is added. So, _double-check your condition_ (`if value == ...`) before. It obviously never evaluates to `True`.
-- Remark: Use the more idiomatic `dictionary[key] = value` for setting and `variable = dictionary[key]` for reading if you do not have good reasons to do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code the issue could be that you use the same `up` dictionary every iteration. Put `up` inside the for-loop:

```py
li = []
for instance in instances:
    up = {}                                  # <-- put `up` here
    for key, value in instance.items():
        up.setdefault(key, value)
        if key == 'instance_id':
            for node in temp:
                if value == (node.get('ec2VirtualMachineSummary', {}).get('instanceID', {})):
                    up.setdefault('displayName', node.get('displayName'))
    li.append(up)
```